# Find a pair in a vector by its first value

Tags: c++11, stl

I have a vector which contains several pairs(INT,INT).
I want to search for a particular but I only have one key of that pair.
How should I search for the second key?

Comment: [`std::find_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) should work for such a search.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12008059/find-if-and-stdpair-but-just-one-element

Comment: Possible duplicate of [find\_if and std::pair, but just one element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12008059/find-if-and-stdpair-but-just-one-element)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following algorithm (pseudo code):

```
let vec be the input vector
let key be the value that you are searching
for each pair p in vec
    let p_1 be p.first
    if p_1 == key
        return you have found the key
```

Here is a functional approach to extract re-usable components:

```
find_if(beg, end, predicate):
    let beg be an iterator to the beginning of a sequence
    let end be an iterator to the end of a sequence
    let predicate be a function from container element to boolean
    for each iterator in beg...end
        let element be what the iterator points to
        if predicate(element)
            return iterator
```

Now, you can define a custom predicate function:

```
my_predicate(p):
    let p be a pair
    let p_1 be p.first
    let key be the value that you are searching
    return p_1 == key
```

And use find_if:

```
let vec be the input vector
found_iterator = find_if(begin(vec), end(vec), my_predicate)
```

It just so happens that the C++ standard library contains `std::find_if` with pretty much identical interface to my pseudo code.